# Windows 'dir' command: date-time parameter (%~tf) empty in /f loop

Tags: windows, date, batch-file, logging, cmd

I am trying to get a list of the files with dates, names, and folders using cmd.

This is the code I am using

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /d /b /s "mypath\*.pdf"') do (echo "%~tf";"%~nxf";"%~pf")
```

Everything goes well except that for some files the date-time field returns empty.

Sample print when it goes well:

```
"date-time";"filename";"directory"
```

and when it goes wrong:

```
"";"filename";"directory"
```

I check those files simply by doing dir and I get

```
X:>dir
 Volume in drive D is X
 Volume Serial Number is X

   Directory of [directory]

  yyyy-mm-dd  hh:mm    <DIR>          .
  yyyy-mm-dd  hh:mm    <DIR>          ..
  yyyy-mm-dd  hh:mm    size     filename
  ....
```

(or by going to Windows Explorer) and there is a date-time there for all files (including the ones not printing their date-time in the for loop).

1. What is going wrong here? Can it be fixed?
2. Is there any (alternative) way to get the file date-time to print?

Comment: To begin with your `dir` command is incorrect! It should probably read as `DIR "mypath\*.pdf" /B /S /A:-D` to recursively list all files within `mypath` whose extension begins with the case insensitive string `.pdf`.

Comment: Thank you! It does work the way I wrote it, but not the way you suggest.

Comment: Your command is wrong, please open a Command Prompt window, type `dir /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key and read the information provided. What you've posted first of all used an unnecessary option `/D` which outputs the lines in a wide format, more than one per line. That option will be negated by the `/B`are format option you've also used. `/B /S` does not list only files, it lists both files and directories, and it does not list everything, some items with some attributes are omitted. `/A:-D` will list everything regardless of attributes but omit directories, _(and you don't want those)!_

Comment: I ran your line as is (except for inserting a valid "mypath" and it doesn't reproduce the issue.  All lines have a date.  Even using a `*` wildcard and getting files and directories...everything gets a time and date.  Is there anything common/special about the filenames that don't have a time and date?  Like spaces in the name or something?  Can you make a [mcve] listing a directory with files with specific names that reproduce the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @user_newbie10, when you suggested that my example doesn't work, because it most certainly does. What you should have done, is directly replace your incorrect `('dir /d /b /s "mypath\*.pdf"')` with my more correct `('DIR "mypath\*.pdf" /B /S /A:-D')`, and it will definitely work better for your purposes.

Comment: @Compo, as I mentioned, it did not output anything. Point taken in the negated option.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen, it is not an issue with all files, just with some files. I was unable to find out why it affects a small minority (<5%). So, in the end, I just wanted an alternative way to fetch the timestamp. I ended up doing it in python, but I'm still interested in knowing the answer

Comment: @user_newbie10, I can guarantee that the only way my offered command doesn't work, and yours does is that you are outputting only directories whose names end with the string `.pdf`. I don't think, based upon your question that is the case, so I'm telling you that you are absolutely wrong, and must have done something different. The most likely thing, is that you decided to not run your code in cmd.exe and ran it in a batch file instead. When you do that, you'd need to make changes to your variables, which would change from `%` to `%%`. Either way, my advice is 100% correct.

Comment: Please show the full filenames of some of the files that don't work.  Perhaps run `attrib` on the file to see if there are any odd attributes (offline, etc.).  If you don't show some concrete data, there's nothing we can do.